# Need Help Clearing elements in a dialog box AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have an AngularJS SPA and one of the pages is a Search page, on the Search page there is a Button called Vendor(s) if I click on the Vendor(s) button a dialog box opens. So far so good.

In the dialog box there is an input field (input ng-model="vendorSearchBy") and a table that display a list of vendors based on what you enter in the input text field.  As soon as you start typing (after 2 characters), the table is loaded with results, with Vendors that match the letters you entered with the vendor name.  Still with me?

Now, the table has three columns; the first column is an input field (check box) to select the vendor (input type="checkbox" ng-init="action=hasVendor(rec_)" ng-model="action" ng-change="vendorSelected(action, rec_)"), the second column is the name of the vendor, and the third column is the description of the vendor.

On the dialog box there are also 3 buttons; OK, Close, and Clear.  On the Clear button is where I need help with.  When I click the Clear button I want this to happens:

1. Clear the input text field.
2. Clear the input check boxes from (if they were checked) checked to unchecked.
3. Clear the table and have no results.

Pretty much clear everything on the dialog box and have an empty input field and an empty table with no results.

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="selectVendorsBox" title="Select Vendors" class="content">
    <div style="margin-bottom: 5px; font-size: 13px; float: left;">
        <label>Search for </label>
        <input ng-model="vendorSearchBy" class="dialog-input" placeholder="Vendor (min 3 letters)">
    </div>
    <div style="width: calc(100% - 270px); float: right;">
        <span style="font-size: 10px; line-height: normal;" ng-repeat="(k,v) in vendors">{{v.shortName}}, </span>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="ui-jqgrid" style="border: solid 1px gray; border-radius: 5px; font-size: 13px;">
        <div class="header" style="text-align: left;">
            Search Results:
        </div>
        <div id="searchGridBox" style="display: block; visibility: visible; height: 450px;">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
                <thead style="width: 100%;">
                    <tr style="width: 100%;">
                        <th style="width: 50px;">Select</th>
                        <th style="width: 300px;">Vendor Name</th>
                        <th style="width: calc(100% - 350px);">Description</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody style="width: 100%;">
                    <tr ng-repeat="rec_ in vsearchresults.content" style="width: 100%;">
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-init="action=hasVendor(rec_)" ng-model="action" ng-change="vendorSelected(action, rec_)"/>
                        </td>
                        <td style="overflow-x: hidden;">{{rec_.shortName}}</td>
                        <td style="overflow-x: hidden;">{{rec_.longDescription}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>  
        <div class="cs-pagination">
            <div style="width: 200px; height: 20px; margin: 0px auto;">
                <div style="float: left; padding-right: 4px;">              
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-seek-first" ng-click="vpage=1" ng-class="{disabled:(vsearchresults.first)}"></span>
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-seek-prev" ng-click="vpreviousPage()" ng-class="{disabled:(vsearchresults.first)}"></span>
                </div>
                <div style="float: left; padding: 0px 4px; border-left: solid 1px gray; border-right: solid 1px gray;">
                    Page: {{vpage}} of {{vsearchresults.totalPages}}
                </div>
                <div style="float: left; padding-left: 4px;">
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-seek-next" 
                        ng-click="vnextPage()" ng-class="{disabled:(vsearchresults.last)}"></span>
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-seek-end" 
                        ng-click="vpage=vsearchresults.totalPages" ng-class="{disabled:(vsearchresults.last)}"></span>
                </div>          
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the JS

```
$scope.vendorSearchBy = null;
$scope.vsearchresults = null;
$scope.vpage = 1;
$scope.vendorsDialog = $('#selectVendorsBox');

/** this code is for the Vendor's dialog pop-up window **/
$scope.vendorsDialog.dialog({
    width: 1100,
    height: window.innerHeight * 0.71,
    resizable: false,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "OK" : function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        "CANCEL" : function( ){
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        "CLEAR" : function() {
            console.log('I am here and I need Help!!');
        }            
    },
    close: function(e, ui) {
    }
});
/** this function opens the Vendor's dialog pop-up **/
$scope.selectVendors = function() {
    $scope.vendorsDialog.dialog('open');
};
$scope.vpreviousPage = function() {
    if( $scope.vsearchresults ) {
        if( !$scope.vsearchresults.first ) {
            $scope.vpage--;
        }
    }       
};
$scope.vnextPage = function() {
    if( $scope.vsearchresults ) {
        if( !$scope.vsearchresults.last ) {
            $scope.vpage++;
        }
    }
};
$scope.vendorSearch = function() {
    if( $scope.vendorSearchBy && $scope.vendorSearchBy.length > 2 ) {
        var vendors = $lookupSvc.Vendors({shortName: $scope.vendorSearchBy}, 20, $scope.vpage-1);
        vendors.$promise.then(function(d) {
            if( d ) {
                $scope.vsearchresults = d;
            }
        });
    }
};
$scope.$watch('vendorSearchBy', function(nv, ov) {
    if( nv ) {
        $scope.vendorSearch();
    }
});
$scope.$watch('vpage', function(nv, ov) {
    if( $scope.vpage ) {
        if( $scope.vpage !== ov ) {
            if( $scope.vsearchresults ) {
                if( $scope.vpage < $scope.vsearchresults.totalPages + 1 ) {
                    $scope.vendorSearch();
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Page out of range.');
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
$scope.hasVendor = function(v) {
    let h = false;
    if( v ) {
        let keys = Object.keys($scope.vendors);
        h = keys.includes(v.shortName);
    }       
    return h;
}
$scope.vendorSelected = function(a, v) {
    if( a ) {
        $scope.vendors[v.shortName] = v;
    }
    else {
        delete $scope.vendors[v.shortName];
    }
};
```

I really hope that you guys can help me with this.

Comment: Clear all the `$scope` variables that is binded to those fields and set the checkbox model to false.

Answer (score 0):

```
"CLEAR" : function() {
            console.log('I am here and I need Help!!');
        }
```

Something like this:

```
$scope.vendorSearchBy = "";
//If the vendor flag is being persisted then unset the flag for each one
//if it's not then this for loop is redundant

for(var i = 0; i < $scope.vsearchresults.content.length; i++){
var currentResult = $scope.vsearchresults.content[i];
//Ensure each listed vendor has its flag set to false
currentResult.action = false;
};

//Set the search results content to an empty object to clear the table
$scope.vsearchresults.content = {};
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and didn't work.  It seems like I need to refresh some how?   know the search results is set to null but the vendors are still there on the table, not even the input text field gets cleared.  do I need to refresh or do a $scope.watch somewhere?

Comment: What happens if you call $scope.apply() after you’ve cleared everything

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, I will try all this again and I will report back